# SonarQube ignores null checking method Validator.isNotNull

Tags: null, sonarqube, liferay, software-quality

SonarQube ignores Liferay's [`Validator#isNotNull`](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0-ga3/javadocs/portal-kernel/com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/Validator.html) method. For example, this snippet

```
if(Validator.isNotNull(foo)){
    foo.doStuff();
}
```

would get mis-classified as a bug:

> A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "foo" is nullable here

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: How should SonarQube know about this method?

Comment: @JeroenHeier That's why I'm asking here